# React cannot set property of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a get request using axios. I know for a fact that when I make a get request, I get the correct data.

I have an array (allQuotes) in my constructor. However, when I try to reference it in componentDidMount, it's undefined.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.allQuotes = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get("http://getquote.herokuapp.com/get")
    .then(function (response) {
      this.allQuotes = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
      this.getNewQuote();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
      //console.dir(error);
    });
  }
```

}

Upon running this, the console says "Cannot set property 'allQuotes' of undefined".

Why is `this` undefined?

Comment: it's because of the scope, that `this` inside the `then()` is not the `this` of the parent function, you gotta bind it, add `.bind(this)` at the end of the function passed to `then()`.

Comment: This guy here is right. Read [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) The very first line of it is "JavaScript’s this keyword behavior has confused developers for ages." and is exactly what you need

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you put `allQuotes` in state then you use `setState`

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      allQuotes: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get("http://getquote.herokuapp.com/get")
    .then(function (response) {
      this.setState({ allQuotes: response.data })
      console.log(response.data);
      this.getNewQuote();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
      //console.dir(error);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrow functions to fix this. The problem is because if its another function, `this` refers to the function, and arrow function doesnt have one, instead it has the `this` of its referer.

```
axios.get("http://getquote.herokuapp.com/get")
    .then((response)=>{
     ...
    })
    .catch( (error)=> {
     ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using react, please make use of state.

What is a state ?

state are both plain JavaScript objects within the component and you can use setState to store the value within the component. You can refer https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

```
  state = {
           allQuotes: []
         }

          componentDidMount() {

            axios.get("http://getquote.herokuapp.com/get")
            .then(function (response) {
              //this.allQuotes = response.data;
              this.setState({
                  allQuotes: response.data
              })
              console.log(response.data);

              this.getNewQuote();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log("Error: ", error);
              //console.dir(error);
            });
          }
```